# How can I use GEKKO optimization while calling a function from outside of the optimization process?

Tags: function, optimization, gekko

Can GEKKO optimization accommodate the utilization of functions to compute some parameters during the optimization process? In other words, can we incorporate the calculation of certain parameters from other functions within our optimization routine?

I'm new to using GEKKO, and I'm wondering if GEKKO can work with calculations from another function while optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can use functions you define before declaring your equations. Ex : let `x` be a model variable and `y` be either a variable or a parameter, you can write

```
m.Equation(x == 3*y**2 + 4)
```

or

```
def fun(a):
   return 3*a**2 + 4

 m.Equation(x == fun(y))
```

But you should be careful not to use a function that is too complex : you must be able to write your Gekko equation without a seperate function. To rephrase, functions ashould only be used to simply the redaction of equations